# How to calculate difference between three time?

Tags: java, android

Works with two different times but not showing correct calculation with three different times.

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date date1 = format.parse(timestart);
Date date2 = format.parse(timeend);
Date date3 = format.parse(breaktime);
long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime() - date3.getTime();
int hours = (int)(mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins = (int) mills/(1000*60) %60;
```

Comment: What output do you expect? Please edit you question to add a concrete example (eg. if `date1` is 08:00, `date2` is 09:00 and `date3` is 11:00, then what is the expected output?)

Comment: What difference are you trying to calculate? You can only really calculate between two separate points, e.g `date1 -> date2` or `date1 -> date3`? Or two differences e.g. `date1 --(diff1)--> date2 --(diff2)--> date3`?

Comment: `date1 -> 10:00` , `date2 -> 17:00` , `date3 -> 00:30` ===output should be 06:30 (date2 - date1- date3)

Comment: You're using an unsuitable object to measure the break time. Vivek's answer is a correct summary, I've also answered with two code solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key problem here is that `date3`, the duration of the break time, is using an unsuitable object. `date1` and `date2` are correctly defined as `Date` objects as they represent times of the day (10:00 and 05:00, as you mention in [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52150923/how-to-calculate-difference-between-three-time#comment91252324_52150923)). However, by setting `date3` to be 00:30, you're declaring it to being a time of day equivalent to **half past midnight today**, instead you want this to be a time period of 30 minutes.

So you'll want to take the difference between `date1` and `date2`, and then subtract the number of minutes taken from the break like this (assuming `breakLength` is 30 minutes for example):

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date date1 = format.parse(timestart);
Date date2 = format.parse(timeend);
long breakLengthMillis = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(breakLength)

long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime() - breakLengthMillis;
int hours = (int)(mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins = (int) mills/(1000*60) % 60;
```

Alternatively, if you want to measure a break by its start and end times, you could use this:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date date1 = format.parse(timestart);
Date date2 = format.parse(timeend);
Date date3 = format.parse(breakStart);       // Start time of break
Date date4 = format.parse(breakEnd);         // End time of break

long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime() - (date4.getTime() - date3.getTime());
int hours = (int)(mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins = (int) mills/(1000*60) % 60;
```

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to calculate:

```
Work_Duration = End_Time - Start_Time - Break_Duration?
```

If yes, you can simply use an integer/long variable to represent break duration in units of your choice (seconds or minutes).  It need not be a Date object.

You can calculate:

```
Break_Duration = Break_End_Time - Break_Start_Time
```

So, you will have 2 `Date` objects (one for start of break, another for the end of break time), instead of just one for breaktime.

Answer (score 0):

If you want calculate the different between timeend end timestart and the different between timeend end breaktime time you need do:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm");
Date date1 = format.parse(timestart);
Date date2 = format.parse(timeend);
Date date3 = format.parse(breaktime);
long mills = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
long mills2 = date2.getTime() - date3.getTime();
int hours = (int)(mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins = (int) mills/(1000*60);
int hours2 = (int)(mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins2 = (int) mills/(1000*60);
```

Because if you do date1- date2- date3 you have a negative number (es 1535983083-1535810283-1535896683)